# oracle.net.keepAlive vs connection pooling (Hikari CP/UCP pool idle connection timeout)

Tags: oracle, jdbc, connection-pooling, hikaricp, ucp

Using connection pools such as Hikari or Oracle UCP, you can set pool size (init size, idle size, max size) and timeouts (idle/inactive connection timeout).

In hikari, you can configure `keepaliveTime` (combined with long idle tiemout / max life time) to prevent firewall killing idle TCP connections (`SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection`)...

But in Oracle UCP, I did not find option to enable connection "keepalive". So there might be option to set it on jdbc driver level - `oracle.net.keepAlive; oracle.net.TCP_KEEPIDLE; oracle.net.TCP_KEEPINTERVAL; oracle.net.TCP_KEEPCOUNT;`

Question:
If I enable keepalive on JDBC driver, what happens to pool's `idleTimeout` when pool size is bigger than `minimumIdle`?

Would the pool drop such connection as "idle" or would it consider "alive" because of keepalive packets and keep it opened?

Thanks

Comment: Based on answers, I have decided not to interfere with ojdbc settings and set ucp to `validateConnectionOnBorrow=true`, `secondsToTrustIdleConnection=1800` to achieve detection of broken connections (because of missing keepalive option in ucp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on answers, I have decided not to interfere with ojdbc settings and set ucp to `validateConnectionOnBorrow=true`, `secondsToTrustIdleConnection=1800` to achieve detection of broken connections (because of missing keepalive option in ucp)

Answer (score 1):

The correct prefix for UCP properties in Spring Boot is spring.datasource.oracleucp (not just ucp as a previous answer)

Answer (score 0):

It seems oracleUCP gives an option for you to set keep alive time.

`spring.datasource.ucp.time-to-live-connection-timeout`

And in general, I don't think it is a good idea to mess with connection settings on the driver level because it could create conflicts!

*reference:* https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jjuar/oracle/ucp/jdbc/UCPDataSource.html#setTimeToLiveConnectionTimeout_int_

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the JDBC driver properties to UCP using setConnectionProperties() API like below.

```
PoolDataSource pds = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("oracle.net.keepAlive", "true");
pds.setConnectionProperties(props);
```

The driver keepAlive settings are transparent to UCP pool, it will close an idle connection if it is inactive from x seconds where x is configured inactive connection timeout on ucp pool.